# Maximum likelihood estimation works with beta-binomial distribution but fails with beta distribution on same dataset

Tags: r, optimization, distribution

I have a dataset of baseball statistics. There's 1 column for `at-bats` and 1 for `hits`.

My goal is to calculate the `alpha` and `beta` parameters for the beta distribution by using `mle` method (Maximum Likelihood Estimation).

```
mlf1 = function (alpha, beta) {
    -sum(dbetabinom.ab(data$hits, data$atbats, alpha, beta, log=T))
}

mlf2 = function (alpha, beta) {
    -sum(dbeta(data$hits/data$atbats, alpha, beta, log=T))
}
```

So `mlfX` is the function to calculate the negative log-likelihood. `mlf1` uses beta-binomial distribution which means that you pass the successes (`data$hits`) and the total observations (`data$atbat`) to calculate. `mlf2` uses *plain* beta distribution, it operates on the proportion of the aforementioned columns. They should essentially yield the same result.

I can execute the following without problems:

```
mle(mlf1, start=list(alpha=1, beta=10) method="L-BFGS-B")
```

It yields `alpha` ~ 74 and `beta` ~ 222

If I execute `mle` with the second negative log-likelihood method:

```
mle(mlf2, start=list(alpha=1, beta=10) method="L-BFGS-B")
```

It gives me this:

```
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

If I modify `mlf2` to filter out players with more than 30 `at-bats` it starts to work.

```
mlf2modified = function (alpha, beta) {
    data = filter(data, atbats > 30)
    -sum(dbeta(data$hits/data$atbats, alpha, beta, log=T))
}
```

**My question is** why is these 2 basically identical approaches makes the optimizer behave completely differently? What can you do to avoid this if you only have proportions and do NOT want to throw out data points because the optimizer is acting up?

UPDATE:

`dbetabinom.ab` is from package `VGAM`, `mle` is from `stats4` and `dbeta` is from `stats`

Comment: Well, the two models above are not identical at all. Furthermore, the error message `L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'` is pretty clear: did you see what happens if you try for instance `dbeta(0,2,10,log=TRUE)`? Not that is relevant to my comment, but you should provide the packages you are using when asking a Q on SO.

Comment: You are right, fixed it! I figured out -thanks to you- that my problem was not the just the zeroes (which results in -Inf) but the ones as well! I tried mlf2modified's 1st line to `data=filter(data, hits/atbats < 1 & atbats > 0 & hits > 0)` and now `mle` executes fine. The problem is that it returns completely different `alpha` and `beta` values. `mu` is almost identical to `mlf1` 's `mu` value (`alpha/(alpha+beta)`) but I still don't get it. Another question still remains: why can I leave out filtering when doing the beta-binomial distribution?

Comment: Well, the beta-binomial model comes directly from the bayesian approach and is sound, robust and derive its validity  from the basic principles of the probability theory. The other approach is kind of meh; I guess it's just a "recipe" to fit some data, but without a proper model behind.

Comment: What is exactly "meh" about it? I don't get the "without a proper model behind" part either. Both beta distribution and beta-binomial distribution are valid probability distributions. The difference is that one is for discrete values and one is for continuous. This difference is the cause that one approach works and the other doesn't. I want to understand the reasons behind the issue.

Comment: Do you know why you are using the beta-binomial distribution and not a gaussian or a logistic or a lognormal distribution?  Do you know where the betabinomial comes from? However, don't think here it's the place to discuss statistic related stuff. I just wanted to stress that the betabinomial comes from a reason and so no exception has to be handled "manually", opposite to other choices which are just recipes and may work often, but can give absurd results in some instances.

Comment: Thanks for your insights and good questions! I'm using it to calculate the posterior distribution for baseball players' batting average. The prior distribution is the empirical distribution of an average player and from that, `alpha0` and `beta0` can be calculated. Since we know the `hits` and `atbats` stats of each player, we use these 2 statistics to update the `alpha` and `beta` values to get a posterior distribution of batting averages. This distribution 'approach' is very intuitive in this scenario. I assumed it should not matter whether I use beta-binomial or beta distribution. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As remarked by the others you are comparing two different approaches to estimate the rates. When using the beta-distribution directly on the y/n you treat each rate as providing as much information as any of the other rate. When you use the beta-binomial you are using both information on y and n, i.e. 1 out of 2 provides less information about the underlying rate being equal to 50% than 100 out of 200 would.

The simplest way to estimate the rate would be to use the binomial distribution, but either because you are being Bayesian about it or because you think the observations have more variance than the binomial does (justifying the extra use of a dispersion parameter) you end up with the beta-binomial distribution. Hence, it's no surprise you get different results if your n's are not all equal.